# Checking if a list contains any one of multiple characters

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python. I want to check if the given list `A` contains any character among `('0', '2', '4', '6', '8')` or not, where `'0' <= A[i] <= '9'`.
I can do this as:

```py
if not ('0' in A or '2' in A or '4' in A or '6' in A or '8' in A):
    return False
```

but, is there any shorter way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can do ```if any(c in A for c in ['0','2','4','6','8'])```

Comment: If you want all the characters, ```if all(c in A for c in ['0','2','4','6','8']) ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `any` with generator expression

```
A = [...]
chars = ('0', '2', '4', '6', '8')
return any(c in A for c in chars)
```

Comment: Thanks! The time complexity of this will be `O(len(chars) * len(A))` or `len(A)`?

Comment: @GURUShreyansh `O(len(chars) * len(A))` but in the worst case, `any` will return True on the first match.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a `for` loop:

```
for i in '02468':
    if i not in A:
        return False
```

If you want `True` to be returned if all of the characters are found:

```
for i in '02468':
    if i not in A:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: @GURUShreyansh Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the data structure [Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
targets = ('0', '2', '4', '6', '8')
A = ('0', '0', '5', '9')

len(set.intersection(set(targets), set(A))) > 1
```

Where, in this case:

```
set.intersection(set(targets), set(A))
#=> {'0'}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I feel `len(set.intersection(set(targets), set(A))) > 0` is enough for my case right?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
A = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
B = ("0", "2", "4", "6", "8")

def contains(list_A, list_B):
    for char in list_B:
        if char in list_A:
            contains = True
    return contains

print(contains(A, B))
```

It goes through each character in list_B and checks if it is in list_A and if it is it sets the variable contains to True.

Then it returns this value

Comment: ```contains``` is a function, and in your code, you do ```contains=False```

Comment: I don't understand. I do ```contains = True```

Comment: ```contains``` is also a function. You have defined it

Comment: I know, but the ```contains = True``` is a local variable and doesn't affect that

Comment: Thanks. But I think we need to define `contains` before the loop otherwise if the list doesn't contain the desired character then it will throw `local variable 'contains' referenced before assignment` error.